# PDT Helios - PHP code mixed with HTML tags cause crash

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

I am working on a WordPress theme, using PDT Helios, and keep having the IDE hanging with error message:  An internal error occurred during: "Semantic Highlighting Job".

The error log reveals that it enters an infinite loop while attempting to parse some PHP. But for the life of me, those are just simple PHP code. What would be causing the hang (removing those lines of PHP prevents the hanging; leaving them in will cause the document to hang)

I have attached the PHP file in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JmCqj1DW). For the life of me, I can't figure what is it that is causing PDT to hang. Other theme files doesn't hang at all.

I have tried:

1. Disabling all web validation
2. Deleting and re-entering the code. It works, till I exit and re-enter PDT and it will just hang again
3. Copying that file to a new project (without WordPress). It doesn't hang, but it's not helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Did some more Googling. Looks like it's a bug.

[Bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315337)